# Grouping same elements in the list efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
arr=[i%m for i in (map(int,(input().split())))]
```

suppose `n=5` and `m =3` and input `array =[3, 2 ,1 ,4, 5]` so `arr=[0, 2, 1, 1, 2]` in this case but now i want to store elements of equal value in a list efficiently i.e  `[1,1]` and `[2,2]`.What's the best way to group them together efficiently?Also i want their indices at the end so

output : [[1,1],[2,2]] from index (2,3) and index(1,4)

what i am looking for is the indices of the original array elements before taking mod that have the same value after performing mod operation.

Comment: No, it can't be done in less than O(N). You need to iterate over all elements once to group.

Comment: So what would the expected output be?

Comment: So `0` isn't included because it's unique? What would an input list of `[1, 2, 1, 1, 2]` be?

Comment: @JonClements [[1,1,1],[2,2]].Yes ,Only those elements are to be grouped together that are repeated.

Comment: Okay - so it doesn't matter if they're contiguous or not and unique elements don't count? Why not just put them in a `collections.Counter` - doesn't seem you really care/need the actual lists (although a counter will let you get elements out quite nicely) and work with that? (and if you really want to expand it out - `[[k] * v for k, v in Counter(arr).items() if v > 1]` ?

Comment: Actually i want their index at the end .counter would count the number of occurrence  of the element but the indices of the elements would be a problem.

Comment: @Demonking28 then maybe you should ask that question then? :) Because there's plenty of ways to group the data - but your example lends itself towards answers that won't immediately be that useful for what you actually are after (and what would the output be based on wanting their indices?)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the input what i am looking for is the indices of the original array elements before taking mod  that have the same value after performing mod operation.

Comment: @Demonking28 okay - you need to make that very clear in the question itself - as it's not obvious and people won't read all the comments... (not to mention - are you able 1-based indices - as Python's are 0-based - so your example indices don't immediately make a lot of sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set` saves only unique values

```
arr=[0, 2, 1, 1, 2]
arr = [(s, arr.count(s)) for s in  set(arr)]
#  [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

update (thanks to @JonClements)

```
s = {}
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
  s.setdefault(v % 3, []).append(i)
print(s)
# {0: [0], 1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 4]}
```

Comment: That could have been done using counter too Counter(arr) but that won't preserve the index. I think i didn't made it clear in the question but now i have edited the question. My apologies.

Comment: Instead of the try/except - use `s.setdefault(v, []).append(i)`

Comment: And then, you might as well go the whole hog and not bother creating `arr` since it's probably not of use by itself and have: `for i, v in enumerate(array):  s.setdefault(v % 3, []).append(v)`

Comment: I did not know the 1st and missed the 2nd from the question text. Thanks you